# what are the p-orbits in the decomposition of Σ into p-orbits.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]
At the bottom in the proof of slow 2, what's the meaning of "restrict the action of G on Σ to an...on Σ"? Since I can't understand that so I don't know what are the p-orbits in the decomposition of Σ into p-orbits. In my mind as Σ is the conjugations of one sylow p-subgroup,and p is one of the conjugation, maybe it means we can see the elements of Σ as the conjugations of p and let G acts on Σ. Is that right? Any way could you tell me what are the p-orbits in the decomposition of Σ into p-orbits?

Comment: You could just screenshot the passage and post it in your question.

Comment: It says $P$-orbit, not $p$-orbit. Note that $p$ is a prime number, and $P$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G$ acts on a set $X$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H$ also acts on $X$. This is restriction.

Comment: Sorry, could explain the meaning of "restrict the action of G on Σ to an...on Σ"?

Comment: @Joseph I just did. $G$ acts on $\Sigma$, and $P$ is a subgroup of $G$, so we can speak of $P$ acting on $\Sigma$. That's what restriction means. What about this *specifically* don't you understand?

Comment: Thanks,but what's a p-orbit?

Comment: Also it doesn't define that G acts on Σ, G only acts on Π.

Comment: @Joseph $\Sigma$ is an orbit (with the action of $G$), so of course $G$ acts on it. Hence $P$ acts on it. A $P$-orbit (notice the capitalization) is an orbit under the action of the subgroup $P$.